# Macro datatype declaration in C

Tags: c, macros

I am studying about memory concepts in C. 
Recently I have come across this piece of code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define check(number) if(number<0){\
                    printf("The given number is negative %d \n",number);\
                    }\
                    else{\
                            printf("given number is positive and is : %d\n",number);\
                        }

int main()
{
    check(6);
    check(-6);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above piece of code I am passing the value 6. Here we have not declared any data type for `number` but even then the macro is taking the default data type that is being passed.
So, how exactly the data type of the `number` is being defined in the macro.

Also where in the memory is this macro expansion taking place and is being stored.

Edit : Here I have taken the code in the macro as just an example. What I really want to know is how is the data type of the `number` being declared.

PS : The question might be lame but I am learning and not able to find the answer.

Comment: Macros are purely text replacement and expansion. They have nothing to do with variable types or memory. Also, the statements are incorrect--`0` is neither positive nor negative.

Comment: What is the point of passing a constant?

Comment: This whole macro is crap: it only works properly with an `int` argument, possibly breaks the calling statement structure and will not be anything faster than a proper function - be it `inline` or not (`printf` alone will take practially all cycles, the rest is irrelevant). It also complicates debugging and inhibits compile-time warnings for wrong argument type. Simply put: DO NOT USE! And no need to further investigate. ("Oh, there is a deep hole in the ground; let's step ahead to investigate what happens when we go further ...")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macros are purely text replacement and expansion. They have nothing to do with variable types or memory.

When you say `check(6)`, the preprocessor finds your `check` macro and **textually replaces** `check(6)` with the following code:

```
if(6<0){
    printf("The given number is negative %d \n",6);
}
else{
    printf("given number is positive and is : %d\n",6);
}
```

The macro expansion has nothing to do with memory. It's just the preprocessor doing simple search-replaces.

Note also that it is highly suggested to wrap macro arguments in parentheses in the expansion, so that you can use expressions when calling your macros. I.e. this would be better:

```
#define check(number) if((number) < 0) {\
                          printf("The given number is negative %d \n", (number));\
                      }\
                      else {\
                          printf("given number is positive and is : %d\n", (number));\
                      }
```

Comment: But in the printf statement we have not declare the data type of `number` variable, so how is it being defined?

Comment: Numerical integer literals have a default type of `int`.

Comment: @Aviig When you call `printf("Here's a number: %d!", 26);`, you aren't defining the type of `26`, are you? It's no different here.

Comment: The macro also replaces `number` that you are still using for the `printf()` argument, with `6`.

Comment: @Aviig: This macro definition *assumes* `number` will always be an integer (that is, the `number` argument will *expand* to something that is either an `int` constant such as `6`, an `int` variable, or an arithmetic expression of `int` type); if you pass something that *doesn't* expand to an integer value or expression, you'll get undefined behavior.

Comment: @JohnBode To add to that, it's undefined behavior because `printf` requires an integer when you write `%d` as part of the format.